# Как убрать ограничение на время исполнения ядер CUDA?

Tags: c, матрицы, cuda

Сделал на C умножение матриц с помощью технологии CUDA. При вычислении матриц больше 3000/3000 драйвер крашится. 
Я слышал, что есть какое-то ограничение на время исполнения ядер. Может быть в этом проблема и стоит увеличить или убрать ограничение?

Comment: У вас Windows? Кажется, когда то давно я писал что-то под OpenCL и сталкивался с чем то похожим. Проблема была вызвана тем, что мои вычисления монопольно забирали все мощности видеокарты и она переставала отвечать на запросы ОС. После этого ОС принимала решение о рестарте драйвера. Читал,что проблему можно решить 2 путями: 1 - правка реестра виндовс для более длительного ожидания(у меня не сработало). 2 - исправление кода так, чтобы он отвечал на запросы ОС

Comment: Про реестр https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2665946/display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-error-in-windows-7
Пункт 3

Comment: Viktorov,  да, Windows 7. Рад слышать, что данная проблема возникала у кого-то. Какими способами можно ответить на запросы ОС? Есть стандартные функции cuda или же надо через windows.h как-то?

Comment: я не работал с Cuda. У меня был чипсет AMD. Если правка реестра не помогла, то больше я ничем помочь не могу

Comment: Как бы я не менял реестр ничего не получается. Довольно печально. Есть правда ещё один способ. Надо как-то включить одновременно дискретную и встроенную видеокарты. Вычисления производить на дискретной, а изображение держать на встроенной. Может и получится тогда

Comment: У меня есть теория, что включить одновременно 2 видеокарты не получится. Я бы капал в сторону варианта, при котором ваша видеокарта отвечает операционной системе

Comment: А вообще, первый вопрос в гугл - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182151/cuda-program-causes-nvidia-driver-to-crash похоже, это должно помочь. Если сработает, оформите тут ответом =)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Правда почему-то сработало не с первого раза данное решение, но вроде все окей пока-что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажимаем на значок windows.
В поиске пишем regedit и запускаем.

Находим 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers`

Создаем `DWORD` `TdrLevel` = `0`.

Перезагружаем компьютер.
Проверяем.

У меня сработало не с первого раза.

Comment: когда я писал про оформление ответа, я говорил не о цитировании ссылки, а о развернутом ответе. Что сделали, как сделали. Чтобы на РуСо появился такой ответ

Comment: Хорошо, я поправлю.